# SQL select rows with a missing value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this :

```
id      group_id    meta
1       A           last_activity
2       A           post_id
3       B           last_activity
4       C           last_activity
5       C           post_id
```

I would like to return only the group_id where there is not the value 'post_id' in column meta

I’ve tried different solutions with `NOT IN`, `<>`, etc. but i can’t get the correct result.

Something like :

```
$sql_group_id = ("SELECT group_id FROM `table` WHERE meta <> 'post_id'");
```

The result would be : `group_id = B`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING SUM(meta='post_id') = 0
```

The query uses a *conditional aggregate* in its `HAVING` clause, in order to filter out groups of records having at least one related record with `meta='post_id'`.

Comment: would you not use COUNT() here rather than SUM()?

Comment: @AdamCopley This is the way we combine *specifically in MySQL* `SUM` with a Boolean expression that returns either 1 or 0. Beware: `COUNT(0)` equals to 1.

Comment: Ahh I see, very nice and a great spot about count(0). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM `table` 
WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT group_id
                       FROM `table`
                       WHERE meta like '%post_id%'
                       GROUP BY group_id);
```

Or could try with:

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM `table` 
WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT group_id
                       FROM `table`
                       WHERE TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM meta like) = 'post_id');
```

Comment: This will also bring A and C

Comment: @apomene According to my test,  it is not working. This was exactly what i was trying to do : using a Subquery with `NOT IN`

Comment: @SébastienGicquel I've used '%post_id%' just to avoid any  trailing space

Comment: sorry, from my testing it is still not working, it returns a blank array. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. The solution given by Gorges Betsos ( @Giorgos Betsos )  is working so i will use it. Just wanted to let you know that i have tested all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the group_ids that have any other meta value. Instead, you should use the `not exists` operator to query those that don't have the meta value of post_id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.group_id = b.group_id and b.meta = 'post_id')
```

Comment: From my testing, it returns all the b.group_id

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select t.`group_id` from(
    select `group_id`, 
    sum(case `meta` when 'post_id' then 1 else 0 end) as `new_col`
    from `table`
    group by `group_id`
)t
where t.`new_col` = 0;
```

Comment: What is `new_col` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
$sql_group_id = ("SELECT group_id FROM `table` WHERE meta not in ('post_id')");
```

Comment: From my testing, it returns all the rows from `table`